# Association bonus after deleting the network profile

Tags: support, deleted-accounts, association-bonus

If you use SE and get the association bonus, proceed to delete your profiles from all SE sites and have your network profile deleted, and then create a new SE profile using the same credentials, will you have the association bonus or not? I cannot answer this question using the FAQ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you would. Even if you delete every single profile and the one on stackexchange.com, your underlying network account still exists, and that is where the association bonus is stored. That underlying account is never deleted, as it contains the history of *what happened* to the account, and knowing why specific profiles were deleted can be valuable information in the future.

Using the same credentials would simply link you back to the existing account and create a new profile on it.

Comment: do I understand correctly that there is no way to delete the network account?

Comment: Correct. There is not.

Comment: Wait, does that mean I can create an account on SuperUser, award 100 of my 101 rep as a random bounty, delete my SuperUser account, recreate one, get 101 rep, give a new bounty etc? What checks are there against that? Or do I get that wrong and it's stored in the network account?

Comment: @Jenayah You can, but you're very likely to receive a very long suspension shortly after to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: Oh sure, wasn't intending to do it, just wondering if there's a check _beforehand_, or if it has to be checked by a human afterwards. Sounds like there should be a block before one tries (to prevent abuse, and in the case of users having forgotten they had an account or something, to explain that it can't be done)

Comment: @animuson what exactly is wrong with that behaviour? It is the SE that is giving the association bounty, not the user. The software allows to do such a thing, in what way is it abusive?